# Preventing repetition through iteration - inbuilt function .uniq [rails4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm new to rails - any help will be much appreciated.
I wanted to know how i implement the rails inbuilt function ".uniq" -

1. I want to display only event organisers in my index.html.erb page - that is, i want to simply display only users who have created events
2. User A has created 2 events, User B has created 14 events, User C has created 0 events
3. When i iterated through @events and call up event.user.full_name - User A's name appears 2 times, User B's name appears 14 times, and User C's name does not appear

> Question: How do i get User A's name & User B's name to appear only
>   once (using the rails inbuilt method ".uniq") though both users have created more than one event. i'm opened to any other suggestion other than the rails function. - Many thanks

I have placed all my codings below:

Views: app/views/users/index.html.erb

```
<% @event.each do |event| %>
    <%= event.user.full_name %>
<% end %>
```

Models: user.rb & event.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Controller: user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @event = Event.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @events = @user.events.order(:date)
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :lastname, :dob, :gender, :description, :role)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @event = Event.all
end
```

Change `@event = Event.all` to:

```
@event = Event.all.to_a.uniq { |e| e.user.full_name }
```

This answers your specific question, but you are still loading all events, and all associated users to those events, only to show a list of names.

I would try something like this:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @users_with_events = User.joins(:events).uniq
end
```

The `@users_with_events` should be reduced to the set of Users with Event relations.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways. You can group the `@event` array based on user

```
<% @event.group_by(&:user).each do |user, events| %>
    <%= user.full_name %>
<% end %>
```

Or, use @user array

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
    <%if user.events.count > 0%>
       <%= user.full_name %>
    <%end%>
<% end %>
```